# Rails way to match two users in real time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm developing a Rails application as a backend for a mobile app, via a JSON API. I've modeled pretty much everything, but there's one (core) process that needs to be designed and I'm not finding a clear way to implement it.

Besides from other features, the app must match two users that meet a certain conditions, mainly geographical. For the sake of the question and to simplify, let's say it needs to match users that are close to each other AND that are currently searching for a match (it's a synchronous experience), e.g.:

- User A hits "Search partners" and a loading screen appears
- User B hits "Search partners" and a loading screen appears

The users are, let's say, 5km apart. The experience should be:

- They both see the loading screen for 5 seconds, while "the system" is looking for matches nearby (3km). After 5 seconds, it broadens the radius to 6km and it matches the two users. The two of them should navigate to the "Found a match" screen.

My main issue here is how to model this "looking for a match" status in Rails. I've thought of creating a table and model including a reference to the user and his position. But then I can't figure out how to deal with the "match query" without falling into a master-slave situation.

Basically, the ideal situation would be one in which both user's apps were in a kind of idle status and the backend, in case of a match, could notify them both, but in that case, the process in the backend should've to be not request-based but maybe a worker...I'm using Postgres with Postgis, so the storage of the user's position is possible, but not sure if maybe Redis would be a better choice, given the amount of changing rows...

I'm aware I'm being quite vague with my question, but it's really a matter of what approach to take, more than a code-level solution.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Read about ActionCable, you can open a websocket conection from each client, and when the match is ready you broadcast the data to both. The users don't have to do anything since websocket connections are biriectional and almost realtime. About the database I wouldn't use redis, it sounds like you need to do some geoposition calculations, maybe you can use mongodb too.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I have no prior experience of the feature you have in mind. But, I would do something like the following.

### Assumptions:

- All code below makes use of Postgis
- `PartnersLocation` model has a `t.st_point :geolocation, geographic: true` attribute. [Reference](https://medium.com/@hin556/location-based-searching-in-rails-5-part-2-using-postgis-extension-7ab2d34b9885)

### Possible Solution:

- Client-side connects to the Rails backend through `ActionCable` (websocket)

  **Example:**

  ```
  // JS
  // when "Search Partner" is clicked, perform the following:

  var currentRadius = 5;

  // let XXX.XX and YYY.YY below to be the "current" location
  // Request:
  //   POST /partners_locations.json
  //     { partners_location: { radius: 5, latitude: XXX.XX, longitude: YYY.YY } }
  // Response:
  //   201 Created
  //     { id: 14, user_id: 6, radius: 5, latitude: XXX.XX, longitude: YYY.YY }

  // Using the `partners_location` ID above ^
  App.cable.subscriptions.create(
    { channel: 'PartnersLocationsSearchChannel',  id: 14 },
    {
      connected: function() {
        this.search()
        // search every 5 seconds, and incrementally increase the radius
        setInterval(this.search, 5000)
      },
      // this function will be triggered when there is a match
      received: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        // i.e. will output: { id: 22, user_id: 7, latitude: XXX.XX, longitude: YYY.YY  }
      }
      search: function() {
        this.perform('search', { radius: currentRadius })
        currentRadius += 1
      }
    }
  )
  ```
- Back-end side would be something like:

  **app/controllers/partners_locations_controller.rb:**

  ```
  class PartnersLocationsController < ApplicationController

    def create
      @partners_location = PartnersLocation.new(partners_location_params)
      @partners_location.user = current_user

      if @partners_location.save
        render @partners_location, status: :created, location: @partners_location
      else
        render json: @partners_location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    private

    def partners_location_params
      params.require(:partners_location).permit(:radius, :latitude, :longitude)
    end
  end
  ```

  **app/channels/application_cable/partners_locations_search_channel.rb:**

  ```
  class PartnersLocationsSearchChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
      @current_partners_location = PartnersLocation.find(params[:id])
      stream_for @current_partners_location
    end

    def unsubscribed
      @current_partners_location.destroy
    end

    def search(data)
      radius = data.fetch('radius')

      @current_partners_location.update!(radius: radius)

      partners_locations = PartnersLocation.where.not(
        id: @current_partners_location.id
      ).where(
        # TODO: update this `where` to do a Postgis two-circle (via radius) intersection query to get all the `partners_locations` of which their "radiuses" have already been taken accounted for.
        # ^ haven't done this "circle-intersect" before, but probably the following will help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166685/postgis-intersect-two-circles-each-circle-must-be-built-from-long-lat-degrees?rq=1
      )

      partners_locations.each do |partners_location|
        PartnersLocationsSearchChannel.broadcast_to(
          partners_location,
          @current_partners_location.as_json
        )

        PartnersLocationsSearchChannel.broadcast_to(
          @current_partners_location,
          partners_location.as_json
        )
      end
    end
  end
  ```

*Code above still needs to be tweaked:*

- just update any of the code above to use JSON API instead
- update the Client-side accordingly (it may not be JS). i.e. you can use:

  - https://github.com/danielrhodes/Swift-ActionCableClient
  - https://github.com/hosopy/actioncable-client-java
- `partners_locations#create` still needs to be tweaked to save both `latitude` and `longitude` into the `geolocation` attribute
- `current_partner_location.as_json` above still needs to be tweaked to return `latitude` and `longitude` instead of the attribute `geolocation`
- `def search` above needs to be updated: the `where` Postgis 2-circle- intersect condition. I honestly don't know how to approach this. If anyone, please let me know. This is the [closest I could find on the web](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166685/postgis-intersect-two-circles-each-circle-must-be-built-from-long-lat-degrees)
- JS code above still needs to be tweaked to gracefully handle errors in connection, and also to stop the `setInterval` after successfully matching.
- JS code above still needs to be tweaked to "unsubscribe" from the `PartnersLocationsSearchChannel` once the "loading-screen" has been closed, or when already found a "match", or something like that (depends on your requirements)

Comment: Isn't your code connecting all the users within a given range?

Comment: @P.Boro yes currently my `def search(data)` method, will try to match all of the "users" even if there are greater than 1 match. I'm not sure yet what the OP wants to do with this, so I leave this currently as is and return all matches. The OP may want to sort and just get the nearest user / `PartnersLocation`, and of which then I'll have to update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq + WebSockets + psql should do just fine. To avoid master-slave situation match making should be based on invites between two looking for match users. The solution is pretty simple: when a user connects via a websocket to your rails app it starts `FindMatchJob`. The job checks if any other user in 5km distance range has invited us and accepts the first invites. Otherwise, it invites other users withing given range and shedules itself again with 1 second delay. I added some code as a proof of concept but it is not bulletproof in terms of concurrency issues. Also I simplified range expansion because I am lazy:)

```
class FindMatchJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(user, range: 5)
    return unless user.looking_for_a_match?

    invites = find_pending_invites(user, range)
    return accept_invite(invite.first) if invites.any?

    users_in_range = find_users_in_range(user, range)
    users_in_range.each do |other_user|
      Invite.create!(
        inviting: user,
        invited: other_user,
        distance: other_user.distance_from(user)
      )
    end

    self.class.set(wait: 1.second).perform_later(user, range: range + 1)
  end

  private

  def find_pending_invites(user)
    Invite.where('distance <= ?', distance).find_by(invited: user)
  end

  def accept_invite(invite)
    notify_users(invite)
    clear_other_invites(invite)
  end

  def find_users_in_range(user, range)
    # somehow find those users
  end

  def notify_users(invite)
    # Implement logic to notify users about a match via websockets
  end

  def clear_other_invites(invite)
    Invite.where(
      inviting: match.inviting
    ).or(
      invited: match.inviting
    ).or(
      inviting: match.invited
    ).or(
      invited: match.invited
    ).delete_all
  end
end
```

One more note. You may want to consider another tech stack to handle this issue. Rails are not the best in terms of concurrency. I would try with GoLang, it would be much better here.